# How to create new page styles to make footers match

Tags: header-footer, pagestyle

I have problems with footers. They don't match.
I was advised to create a new page style for two footers. But I didn't success. I just don't get it what I'm doing wrong.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\date{}
\usepackage[margin=1.15in]{geometry}
    \geometry{
        a4paper,
        tmargin=1.8cm,
        lmargin=1.5cm,
        rmargin=1.5cm,
        bmargin=1.8cm
 }
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{sectsty}
    \sectionfont{\fontsize{28}{31}\selectfont}
    \subsectionfont{\fontsize{21}{24}\selectfont}
\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\usepackage{ifthen}       
        \newif\IfCloudAlly
        \CloudAllytrue
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[3][]
{
  colframe = #2!25,
  colback  = #2!10,
  arc=0pt,auto outer arc,left=1pt, boxsep=10pt, boxrule=1pt,width=\columnwidth,right=1 pt
  #1,
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{MS Exchange User Manual} % левый верхний колонтитул
\fancyhead[R]{{\includegraphics[height=0.96cm, width=4.74cm]{CloudAlly/Screenshots/CloudAlly_aZIXcompany_fin_GRB.png}}} % правый верхний
\fancyfoot[L]{{CloudAlly - Visit our Customer Support Hub: \href{https://support.cloudally.com}{https://support.cloudally.com}}} % левый нижний
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % линия под верхним к.
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} % линия над нижним к.
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \definecolor{links}{HTML}{16e5fe}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        linkcolor=16e5fe,
        urlcolor=links
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\section*{Preface}
\subsection*{Welcome}
\subsubsection*{About this Guide}
    Thank you for selecting Www Backup for MS. Www ensures that your organization’s data is well protected and always available for swift restore to keep your business operational and your employees productive. We empower end users to correct their own mistakes, and give application administrators, IT leadership and audit teams the confidence and proof that your data is appropriately backed up, safe and ready for recovery. Www strives to build real relationships with our customers and deliver exceptional service. 
    We hope this User Guide will help your organization to utilize cloud advancements, aimed at preventing critical business data loss. Our mission is to develop & support advanced software, and to provide better service to our customers. If you ever have a question or need additional help, please contact us at \href{support@www.com}{support@www.com} or search our Knowledge Base at \href{https://support.www.com}{https://support.www.com}.

\linespread{1}\subsection*{Audience}
    This guide is intended for individuals who administer www Backup for MS.
\subsection*{What’s in this Guide }
    This guide is organized to help you find the information you need to manage www Backup for MS. It is divided into functional parts intended to support you as you manage your environment.

\subsection*{Configuration}
\subsubsection*{Prerequisites}
    To administer the www Backup for MS environment, the following is required:
\begin{itemize}
    \item Microsoft for Business 
    \item Global Administrator account in Microsoft online services (Microsoft, SharePoint Online or Microsoft Azure)
    \item www Backup for MS subscription 
\end{itemize}

\section*{Create and Access Your www Account}
\subsection*{Sign Up/Sign In from the Www Home Page }
\begin{enumerate}
    \item In your Internet browser open \href{www.www.com}{www.www.com} and click \textbf{Log In} link.

    The \textsl{Sign In} page is displayed. 

    \item Click \textbf{Don't have an account link.}

    The \textsl{Sign Up} page is displayed. 

\includegraphics[width=380]{Www/Screenshots/Sign up for 14 Day Free Trial.png}

    \item Fill-in the form and click the \textbf{SIGN UP} button.
\begin{mybox}{red}[left=1.07cm, right=1.11cm]
    \textbf{Note}: In addition to the primary AWS data centers available in the dropdown menu "Location", we also offer a “Bring Your Own Storage” (BYOS) option on request. This allows you to store backups in your own AWS S3 buckets, S3 compatible storage service, Azure or Google Cloud Platform. Please contact \href{support@www.com}{support@www.com} for more information.
\end{mybox}

    \item Your trial account is created and an email containing your activation link is sent to your email address. Click on the activation link contained in the email you receive, to activate your account. If you sign up with Google, Azure, Okta the activation link will not be sent to you.
    \item Once your account is activated, you are redirected to the Www login page. Enter your email address/password and click the \textbf{SIGN IN} button to login and access your Www account.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How it looks in pdf.
I need them to be similar to each other.
The image for test [image]

Comment: Please provide an example that demonstrates the problem, we can not run the fragment posted and it references an image file and font not provided (the image is probably not relevant  so you should be able to make an example without it (or use the `example-image` image which is available for tests)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've changed, please try again.

Comment: it can still not be run (no `\documentclass`) I guessed `\documentclass{article}` but what tex engine tdo you use?? the file has `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` which is not for xetex or luatex, but has `\usepackage{fontspec}` which is only for luatex or xetex, and then uses Calibri font (which is only available on windows), with luatex I get the error `! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.` and `! LaTeX Error: Environment documentation undefined.`  and it produces no output so impossible to test the footer text.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use XeLatex, but I can run perfectly. Never mind, I've changed.
What about this error ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor. I don't know how to fix it. But this error doesn't prevent me to run my doc.

Comment: after _any_ error the PDF is not usable, tex's error recovery is not designed to make usable pdf after an error, just recover enough to check the remainder of the docuemnt tcolorbox loads xcolor then you load it again with different options, hence the error

Comment: please copy the code above to a new folder and try to run it, as well as the option clash there are multiple errors with undefine `documentation` and  missing `\begin{document}`  and it produces no output. How can we hep debug your footer problem. is `\begin{documentation}` a typo for `\begin{document}` ???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I fixed the slips with from documentation to document.

Comment: Changed documentclass from article to paperletter and It worked.